# Which user does AWS ELB run under for a predeploy hook?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a file called `.platform/hooks/predeploy/01.download.py`. When I `sudo` into the instance, it looks like the user is `ec2-user`, so the `~/` folder points to `/home/ec2-user`. But when my app runs, it seems that `~/` points to `/home/webapp`. How can I get my `predeploy` script to know the location of `/home/webapp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which user does AWS ELB run under for a predeploy hook?

It runs as `root` and folder `~` points to `/root`, not `/home/ec2-user`.

If you want your scripts to run under different user, e.g. `ec2-user`, you can use the following in your deployment scripts:

```
runuser -l ec2-user -c '<command>'
```

or any variation of it or other similar tool as shown, for instance, [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/),

Comment: What folder does it run in by default?

Comment: @Shamoon It should run in `/var/app/staging` folder.

Comment: What use does the normal app run under once everything is deployed?

Comment: @Shamoon I think it still will be root, but would have to check. But the folder will be `/var/app/current`